# Missing jump to source

Tags: pdf, miktex, texworks, forward-inverse-search

I used to be able to right click on the pdf and the bottom of the list would be a "jump to source" option which would take me to the source code where I had clicked on the pdf. It is no longer there how do I get it back?

I am using Miktex 2.9 and texworks. Sorry I can't be more informative I am not very computer literate.

Comment: Do you have any non ascii chars in the folder path to your PDF? Such as `c:/Users/André/Documents`, at least earlier TW versions might have problems with this regarding synctex. When you compile does it shortly mention `synctex` at the bottom left of the PDF viewer? If it does not then `synctex` is broken for some reason

Comment: The same problem may occur if your *.tex file has spaces in its name. This holds true for my MikTex 2.9 running under Win7. The *.synctex.gz file simply is not created. Unexpectedly, there is no explicit error message addressing this problem during compilation.

Comment: It can also happen if you have non-ascii letters in the folder name leading up to the file or in the filename itself.

Comment: @daleif, would You care to add Your comment as an answer, so I can upvote You? Your suggestion saved the day for me :)

Comment: @Rauni, answer added.

Comment: @daleif upvoted.

Comment: I just had the same problem. I removed the auxiliary files and now it appears the option "jump to source"

Answer (score 3):

Synctex is a bit frizzy about file names and paths. On some systems it may not like non ascii letters in file names or paths. In order to test, create a folder called, say, `latex-test` in the root, i.e. `c:`, copy your file there and see if synctex works.

Answer (score 2):

This functionality is provided by synctex - without more information it's not possible to say why it's gone.

Also Ctrl+left click would be the hotkey for this feature.

I have "$synctexoption" as a compiling parameter from pdfLaTeX - look if that one is set in texworks.

Comment: Ctrl+ left click doesn't work either does this help?

Answer (score 1):

This phenomenon can happen if you haven't compiled the document recently. Try recompiling and check whether the menu item reappears.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [oerpli](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/33556/oerpli), the synctex option is key.

But it may happen even if you have the synctex option, if you have not compiled since you deleted the *.synctex.gz file (e.g. by doing File > Remove Aux Files...)